# What can a vegetarian eat on a low carb diet?

Tags: diet, food, carbohydrate, low-carb

I'm a vegetarian and would like to go on a low carb (preferably no carb) diet. Currently I am getting about 200grams of protein from protein shakes and eggs. Until now I have been eating rice, noodles, etc. as my other food sources. These actually filled me up and gave me energy. I fear without carbs I will feel weak and unable to function.

It seems like no/low carb dieters get the majority of their calories from meats. As mentioned I am already taking 200grams of protein so that's not a problem. I just need foods that will keep me full and energized. What low/no carb vegetarian food options are there that will do this?

Also are fibrous carbs okay to eat on this type of diet? Like broccoli, cauliflower, and other greens (I heard they don't get absorbed and can be thought of as "free" foods)?

Comment: Focus on fats instead of protien. BTW, this question is off topic. Voting to close.

Comment: Can you outline what fitness goals you are trying to achieve and how the very low/no carb diet will assist in that?

Comment: @JohnP I'm just trying to lose body fat. I tried a low calorie diet many times before, the most recent one lasting about 4 months earlier this year. On it I lost about 20lbs but then plateaued and couldn't lose anymore. I wasn't exercising during this diet. Now I am doing tabata burpees for 4 min per day and attempting the low carb approach which I never tried before. I'm reading a book called "Why we get fat and what to do about it" and it makes some good points for the low carb diet. I will also start some weight training soon.

Comment: Are you referring to the Ketone diet? If you are, its about high FATS, LOW protein, and pretty much zero carbs. Its great for rapid fat loss but cannot be considered a long term eating plan.

Comment: @Mike S well the book I'm reading is more of a scientific study, it doesn't really outline a detailed diet. But yes I am looking for a long term plan. I don't want to take little protein because I am also interested in building mussel for which I will begin weight training soon.

Comment: Whats your height/weight and estimated body fat percentage?

Comment: @MikeS Why can't the ketogenic diet be considered long term?

Comment: @JakeRow123 Tabata burpees + low carb is not a great recipe. Tabata type workouts are very glycogen dependent, which means you will need carbs, or you run the risk of using up all glycogen, which will make you feel bad. Weight training is not so glycogen dependent, so if you go very low carb, you might just do that without the tabata workout.

Comment: @michael I have nothing against it for health reasons (as long as there is enough fibre and micro-nutrient supplementation), its more about practicality. We live in a very carb-rich society. Try going out to a restaurant or being invited over to someone's house and trying to stay on only fat and some protein. If you try decreasing your carb calories to 30% of your daily calories, your body will still be on a glycogenic metabolism and will convert excess protein and fats to the missing sugars in your diet. Eat enough calories while eating low carb, and you won't have energy problems in the gym.

Comment: @MikeS I agree that eating against societal norms is hard. Regarding eating enough, I can tell you from experience that glyco-neogenesis does not work fast enough to keep up with crossfit type workouts and tabata. For many other workouts, it does, but glycogen dependent workouts deplete muscle glycogen faster than it can be replaced by the body, no matter how much you eat, and tabata burpees definitely falls into this category.

Comment: @MikeS MMA fighters do workouts called "Glycogen Depletion" workouts to intentionally get into this depleted state in order to then train to simulate being completely gassed at the end of a round.

Comment: @Mike S I'm 180 lbs and 5'8. My body type is overweight. I have a lot of excess fat in my belly region.

Comment: @JakeRow123 Since you are on this path anyway, the next steps after Taubes are Sisson and Wolfe. They will give you better advice than we can. Good luck.

Comment: If your aim is to get rid of excess fat as quickly as possible, I would recommend about 2000 calories + strength training. Michael is right in stating that strength training isn't as dependant on glycogen. As a vegetarian, make eggs/whey protein your friend and try 50% of your calories from protein, with fat next and carbs last. Rep until your drop - and enjoy the process :).

Comment: @Mike S how can I get rid of fat through weight training? I thought cardio was the only way to lose fat and weight training was to build mussel.

Comment: Cardio is NOT the most efficient way to improve your body composition. Your bodies ADAPTIVE response is always the most prominent one. Through cardio, your body burns fat (and muscle) so that you have enough fuel to continue doing your activity. In other words, your body EATS itself to supply enough fuel for your endurance activity. Strength training, BUILDS your body and causes it to ADAPT to hold potential energy stores as muscle not fat. Eating a controlled diet whilst strength training and NO CARDIO is the single most best thing I've ever done for my physique.

Comment: To everyone here, please use the comments to discuss and improve the question at hand. If you have other issues, there are other way or places to deal with those.

Comment: @MattChan Oh Matt, the question was already closed anyways...